# PHP - Best Fit Simulation

Tags: php, algorithm

I'm trying to produce a web app that simulates the Best Fit memory allocation algo. I encounter errors when trying to sort my jobs.

```
$bestfit = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $_POST['holyhole']; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < $_POST['holyhole']; $j++) {
        if ($holecopy[$i] < $holecopy[$j]) {

            $thresh = $holes[$i];
            $holecopy[$i] = $holecopy[$j];
            $holecopy[$j] = $thresh;


            $hold = $bestfit[$i];
            $bestfit[$i] = $bestfit[$j];
            $bestfit[$j] = $hold;
        }
    }
}
$holecopy2 = $holecopy;
for ($i = 0; $i < $_POST['proc']; $i++) {
    $flag = 0;
    for ($j = 0; $j < $_POST['holyhole']; $j++) {
        if ($proc[$i] < $holecopy[$j]) {
            echo ($bestfit[$j] . " " . $holecopy[$j] . " " . $proc[$i]);
            $holecopy[$j] = $holecopy[$j] - $proc[$i];
        } else {
            $flag++;
        }
    }
    if ($flag > $_POST['holyhole']) {
        echo "Wait: " . $proc[$i];
    }
}
```

$thresh and $hold are temporary holder variables. $holecopy is the array of the memory holes, and $proc is the array for jos.

I get an offset error around the lines where I use the bestfit array. I'm having trouble understanding why. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know what kind of madness this is but var-dump($bestfit) before starting the 2nd loop. Does it have the contents you are expecting? Ultimately you're referencing bestfit[$j] which doesn't exist at the moment you're referencing it.